# Menu bar on the top of iPad:)

Tags: ipad

I have created Login page and applied navigation method to switch next View on sign in button. Now I want menu bar with icons button on every next view. I  tryed with tool bar on each each views with two buttons but didnt successed to switch very last view to first view.
   I can switch next view & previous view only. Is there any standard code for menu bar as I have saw menuBar at the top in video for SAP businessOne application. plz help..

Comment: I am developing iPad app. plz help

Comment: By d way I got my answer. I have creat navigation bar programmaticaly (navigation initWith RootViewController) in my one class. Then I hide navigation bar by coding & took ToolBar with same button icons on each next screen. On each next screen class I gave button click event. So I can see the common toolbar with same common button on the each screen like a MenuBar. And its working correctely.

Comment: Hello, could you give me some example code of how to do it? Many thanks.

Comment: -(IBAction)yourClass:(id)sender{
 //[firstViewObj release]; 
 
 yourClass *signupObj = [[yourClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourClass" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:signupObj animated:YES];
 [signupObj release];
 
 
 
}

Comment: use above button click event And Take toolbar with common buttons on every class UI. So when you click ToolBar button above u will get the desire page(like home, settings pgs are common for all screes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(IBAction)yourClass:(id)sender{
 //[firstViewObj release]; yourClass *signupObj = [[yourClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourClass" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:signupObj animated:YES]; 
[signupObj release]; }`

use above button click event And Take toolbar with common buttons on every class UI. So when you click ToolBar button above u will get the desire page(like home, settings pgs are common for all screes)